# Установка Android Studio,

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Здравствуйте! Извиняюсь если будет повтор, но мне хотелось бы ... получить определенный ответ. Я новичок. Раньше я работала с eclips-ом. Теперь работаю на Студио. Я установила Андроид Студио как по инструкцию (где не нашла в интернете и здесь). Андроид Студио 3.0.1. 
Проблема: 
андроид установила, SDK хотела установить в папку Д.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начинается загрузка после "next". В конце дает ошибку:что не получилось загрузить. 
Несколько раз попробовала, но так же результат. Никакие платформы не установлены.  
Я скачала sdk-tools-windows копировала в эту путь. Все равно недоступен никакие платформы. 
В форуме говориться что нужно установить старую версию (например 2.3.2).  
Но я бы хотела знать что я не так делаю. Можно же работать в этой версии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте скачать SDK и положить в папку со студией, дальше в самой студии указать путь до SDK.
Скачать SDK: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html 
вниз полистайте.

Comment: Здравствуйте,  не знаю почему? Но после вашего ответа, оно сработало. Спасибо вам большое.

Comment: Извините, как отразиться если sdk находиться на диске С или на Д. Можете объяснить разницу. И почему по умолчанию оно находиться на AppDate-e?

Comment: @user если ответ Вам помог, примите пожалуйста его, нажав на кнопочку возле мое ответа. Без разницы где находится SDK, главное в самой студии указать ее местоположение